# How to get all row ids of jqgrid by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I want to get all row ids by use of row css class of a jqgrid in a method called in gridcomplete.But it is only returning rows of current page.
I want to get all row ids present in the jqgrid.
Below is my code.

```
function GetAllCompanyProducts(productData) {
/// <summary>method to load the Proposal grid</summary>
//Load the grid
var tabelWidth = $("#tblCompanyProducts").width();

jQuery("#tblCompanyProducts").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: productData,
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
    loadui: "block",
    autowidth: true,
    mtype: 'get',
    rowNum: 30,
    rowList: [30, 100, 200],
    viewrecords: true,
    colNames: ['ProductId', 'ProductName', 'Price'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId', width: '30%' },
        { name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', width: '30%' },
        { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: '30%' }
    ],
    sortname: 'ProductId',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    caption: "Product List",
    width: tabelWidth - 10,
    pager: '#divPager',
    height: "100%",
    hoverrows: true,
    onPaging: function () {
        $("#tblCompanyProducts").trigger('reloadGrid');
    },

});    


$("#tblCompanyProducts").jqGrid('setGridParam', { gridComplete: MakeGridRowsDraggable($("#" + this.id)) });
```

}

```
function MakeGridRowsDraggable(grid) {
/// <summary></summary>
/// <param name="grid" type=""></param>

//$("#tblCompanyProducts").val(new Date().getTime());
var searchResultsRows = $("#tblCompanyProducts .ui-row-ltr");
```

}

The above code returning only the rows set in the first page.
Can anybody help me on this..

Comment: Please post some html

Comment: Are you sure hidden jqgrid 'pages' are part of the DOM? update: i quick check tell me they aren't.  Now you should tell why would you need that?

Comment: The post is edited.Please check..

Comment: A.Wolff, I was trying to make all rows draggable in the grid complete method but now only the first page rows are draggable.

Comment: You need to bind that sort of functionality to elements from inside the plugin API. I haven't used jQgrid for a few years but should have rendering callbacks you would use.